# Searching a list and replacing value if any item matches any item in the other list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, regexplace

I have a list of usernames on two different sheets. I need to scan the first list of usernames to see if they appear in the second, and if they do, replace them with a predefined username. I can't seem to find a built-in function that does this as they all assume a single value and not a list of values to match against. For example, I tried:

```
=SUBSTITUTE([source value],'list of values to look for the source value in'!A:A,"static string")
```

but this didn't trigger, no replacement happened. (source_value should have been changed to 'static string', or I should have the static_string in the next cell over in a new column).

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

Try REGEXPLACE instead :

```
=REGEXREPLACE([source value],TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,'list of values to look for the source value in'!A:A),"static string")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, C2:D, 2, 0), A2:A))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&A2:A, "(^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, C2:C)&"$)", "$1_♥"))
```

[image: 0]